# Cordinates in database within radius of users cordinates?

Tags: android, location

I'm trying to find a way to make the application only show locations that are stored in the database if the cordinates from the location in the database are within the radius (10km) of the users cordinates. I have no idea how I can make this happen.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do a little research. Google "how to calculate distance between coordinates".

Comment: I did do a little research but that's only half of the question

Comment: Based on your new information you surely should be able to try something. This isn't a "write-code-for-me" site. Try, and when you stumble into a specific problem then ask. Someone will surely help.

Comment: If you don't know where to start, here's a clue: iterate through the db, on each entry compare coordinates, get distance and include if smaller than radius. Other way, take user's coordinates, find coordinates to rough corners of a radius-wide box, query db for coordinates within the box.

Comment: Ok thanks, will do that

Answer (score 0):

Pythagoras is your friend. I don't know the exact syntax for your purpose but the formula is:

> Your position: (youX, youY)
>
> Target coordinates: (targetX, targetY)
>
> x= targetX - youX
>
> y= targetY - youY

Valid coordinates must fulfill this formula:

> sqrt(x * x + y * y) < 10km